# java cookie operation gets trouble in firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, cookies

I write java code

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    Cookie[]  cookies = request.getCookies();

    if(cookies == null)
    {
        System.out.println("nullsssss");
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookieExample", "this");
        cookie.setMaxAge(10*60);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        return ;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<cookies.length && cookies[i]!=null ; i++)
    {

        if(cookies[i].getName().equals("cookieExample"))
        {
            System.out.println("getit");
            response.getWriter().write("cookieExample: "+cookies[i].getValue());

        }

    }

}
```

it works fine in chrome .But in firefox it get trouble,I can't get the cookie I set,the cookie "cookieExample=this"
Firefox(version 25.01):
[image]
why?**Is the code something wrong?**

Comment: We can't tell why the screen capture means "trouble".  The cookie in your screen cap looks like it comes from some other site.  Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I add the cookie Cookie("cookieExample", "this") to firefox,but I can't get it,and when I see the cookie in firefox  it shows like the screen capture . I don't kown why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the incoming request has one or more cookies already you code does not ever add the `cookieExample` cookie.  What is likely happening is that your Firefox browser has a cross-domain cookie left over from some prior website you visited, while Chrome does not.  That cross-domain cookie is preventing your code from setting your desired cookie.

Comment: Thanks,I remove all the cookie,then refresh the page , it works :)